# Call python script from ORacle trigger?

Tags: python, oracle, triggers

Is there a way to call a python script from an oracle trigger?

I have a table and every time I insert data can I call a Shell or Python script. Or Should I use cron or SCN or something?

Comment: What do you want the python script to do?  What is the business problem you're trying to solve?  My guess is that you really want some sort of queue or polling mechanism...

Comment: Whenever there is an insert I want to pull the data from the table and display it in the browser

Comment: If that's the case, it would seem to make much more sense for the web page to include some Javascript that polls the database periodically for changes.  There are numerous articles on AJAX periodic refreshes that you can consult http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh